# Google Maps API 3 referrerNotAllowedMapError

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cdn, cloudflare

I'm no stranger to Google Maps APi, and have used it for years...but I am stumped.  I've installed an exact copy of the latest code sample from Google Maps Javascript API: Simple Map.  I then confirmed both my browser and server keys from Google Developers Console, added the refer two different ways(see below).  Code works when I set the referer to * wildcard in console, but cannot use that in production.

Here's the skinny:

- tested using latest example code from Google Maps API Javascript (Simple Map)
- *YOURAPIKEYHERE* - replaced with an active browser key from my account
- referer was tried as both *./domain.ext/* and domain.ext/*
- Also tried a server key, with server IP as allowed referer.
- **CANNOT USE, BUT WORKED** : used a wildcard for allowed referer using browser key, *but I can't use that in production...anyone could use my key on my dime*

**SUSPECTED CULPRIT**

Since the key works when I add a wildcard, but not with the referer domain name, it seems suspicious.  This *should* indicate that the key works, but that the referer information is not getting passed to Google.

My site is behind CloudFlare.  My research is not finding any answers anywhere, but I'm beginning to wonder if this could be the issue.  Nothing else seems to work.

[image: errormessages]

Comment: Why the downvote with no comment?  I fully researched all similar posts, spend hours testing, and provided the details.  I'll add some pretty pictures.  =)

Answer (score 19):

**SOLUTION:**
The google console specifically shows the format for this.  But it is WRONG.

Instead of `*./domain.ext/*`
use: `http://domain.ext/*`

A special thanks to Google for crappy docs, and a very special thanks to the user that downvoted my question!

*Note: Depending on your setup, it may be necessary to use: `http://www.domain.ext/*`
I did not test this as my use case excludes www.*

Comment: As of June 22, 2016, Google made changes that caused the above error and the above solution to be necessary for all new usages of the google maps API. 
I not only found a brand new problem, but also posted the solution.  And some toolbags decided to downvote me for saving the world.  "Welcome to Stack Overflow, where a few toolbags run off the noobs."

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted, but this solution worked for me - I think this might have to do with DNS setup (I also use Cloudflare). Keep on keeping on :)

Comment: thank you so much fantisy!!
this worked for me as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know you found a misconfiguration in your API key but I had the same issue and found a different fix.

Cloudflare can mess this up.  Testing with mine now shows rocket loader and Brotli in the speed area stop google maps working.  Deactivate them and clear the cache to fix.

Comment: I've just had to disable only Rocker Loader in my case. Started with disabling both and then tested that Brotli can be turned on safely. In any case, thanks for the answer Will. Saved me potentially hours trying to figure this out.